# Little heat at idle great heat when reving engine

Tags: dodge, car, heater

I have new radiator put in due to leak, 96 Dodge Ram Van 1500.

I have little to no heat, changed t-stat, flushed heater core, burped system on incline. Heat is slightly better. When I rev the engine it has great heat; let off and let idle, heat goes away.

Please help all answers appreciated! Next thing is the water pump. No leaks anywhere! Temp gauge reading normal then drops to 1/3 mark.

Answer (score 1):

Two areas I think I'd look at:

- Did you put the right thermostat in (temperature wise)? And did it get put in the correct way? If a colder than normal thermostat was inserted, it could possibly cause this issue. If it was put in upside down, there would be a greater chance. One of the main things which is bothering me here is you saying engine temperature is normal at idle, and goes down when you rev the engine. I'm not sure if there is even enough room to put the t-stat in upside down, but when it is, it can cause some strange issues. Coolant will not flow correctly if it is.
- I don't know if the Dodge's have this issue, but I have seen some water pumps which have there impeller eaten away by corrosion. Absolutely kills water flow. Yours may be in the some stage of this. Unfortunately, the only way to tell is by removing the water pump. This would cost you some time and a gasket or two to find out.